# Unable to connect to fetch the data using php class

Tags: php

I'm using XAMPP on Windows XP and when I try to fetch the data from table i am getting below Warnings but not data.

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Chil\class.StudentDet.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in D:\xampp\htdocs\Chil\class.StudentDet.php on line 10

Please find the code below.

Code:

```
class.DBConnection.php

   <?php

      class DBConnection //create a class for make connection
      {
         var $host='localhost';
         var $username='root';    // specify the sever details for mysql
         Var $password='';
         var $databaseName='test';
         var $connectionString;

function connectToDatabase() // create a function for connect database
{
$this -> connectionString = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);             
    if(!$connectionString)// testing the connection
    {
        die ("Cannot connect to the database");
    }       
    mysql_select_db($this -> databaseName,$this -> connectionString);
    if(mysql_error()) // if error occured display the error message
    {
        echo "Cannot find the database ".$this->database;
    }
    return $this -> connectionString;
}
 function closeConnection() // close the connection
{
    mysql_close($this->connectionString);

    echo "Connection closed";
 }
 }
?>
```

class.StudentDet.php

```
 <?php
    require_once('class.DBConnection.php');
    class StudentDet{   

    function getStudDet(){  
    $connection = new DBConnection();
    $connection->connectToDatabase();
    $ct="SELECT * FROM students where course='Testing'";        
    $result = mysql_query($ct); 
    return $result;  
 }
  }
 ?>
```

In Php Page

StudentInfo.php

```
     <?php

      include ('class.StudentDet.php');
      $stud = new StudentDet;
      $fetch = $stud->getStudDet();
      print '$fetch';
    ?>
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Clearly, your MySQL user or password is wrong.

Comment: Did you start your XAMP mysql database on the control panel? have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

where call this function ?

```
function connectToDatabase() // create a function for connect database
{
$this -> connectionString = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);             
    if(!$connectionString)// testing the connection
    {
        die ("Cannot connect to the database");
    }       
    mysql_select_db($this -> databaseName,$this -> connectionString);
    if(mysql_error()) // if error occured display the error message
    {
        echo "Cannot find the database ".$this->database;
    }
    return $this -> connectionString;
}
```